# accessing object in different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

two class here:

```
class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass();
        map<int,int> int_map;
};


TestClass::TestClass()
{

    printf("TestClass1 addr(%p) \n",this);
}
TestClass2::TestClass2(TestClass* tc){
    tc1 = tc;
    printf("TestClass2 get TestClass1 ,addr(%p) !\n",tc1);
}





class TestClass2
{
    public:
        TestClass2(TestClass* tc);
        void Run();
        TestClass* tc1;
};


void TestClass2::Run(){
        int i = 0;
        while(true){
        tc1->int_map.insert(make_pair(i,1));
        printf("TestClass2:size of TestClass1(%p) int_map is %d!\n",tc1,tc1->int_map.size());
        sleep(2);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and the main fun

```
int main()
{
    TestClass* tc1 = new TestClass();
    printf("tc1 addr is %p!\n",tc1);
    TestClass2* tc2 = new TestClass2(tc1);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        while(1){
            sleep(1);
            printf("TestClass1 :%p int_map size %d!\n",tc1,tc1->int_map.size());
        }
    }else{
        tc2->Run();
    }

}
```

the size of int_map in TestClass should be the same when it was printed in different thread.

tc2->Run() print out the right value,
but i got 0 in child thread though tc1 points to the same address in two thread.

Comment: You don't use threads, [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) creates *a new process!*

Comment: but when accessing the object at same address ,the result could be different?

Comment: "fork() creates a new process by duplicating the calling process."  and "The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces.  At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same content.  memory writes, file mappings (mmap(2)), and unmappings  (munmap(2)) performed by one of the processes do not affect the       other.